# Missing Value Search in string seperated by comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Please help me if it is possible in sql.**

Hello, may anyone please share their expertise, i am not very sure whether it is possible in SQL

SIZE OF TABLE: 5GB

I am trying to see invalid `VALIDATION_ID` present in a child table for a given `PRODUCT_LINE`

SO in below scenario 114 is not present for `PRODUCT_LINE` Passive in master table but present in child table.

```
DECLARE @CHILD TABLE
(
  PRODUCT_LINE VARCHAR (50),
  COMPONENT VARCHAR (50),
  MODEL VARCHAR (50),
  YEARS VARCHAR (50),
  VALIDATION_ID VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @CHILD

SELECT 'PASSIVE','RESISTOR','CARBON','2005','V114' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','RESISTOR','CARBON','2005','V098, E009, V034'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','RESISTOR','CARBON','2005','V201'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','RESISTOR','CARBON','2005','V201,V098,V114' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','RESISTOR','CARBON','2005',null  UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','RESISTOR','CARBON','2005','null,V098,E009'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','RESISTOR','CARBON','2005','null,V114'  UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM @CHILD

DECLARE @PARENT TABLE
(
  PRODUCT_LINE VARCHAR (50),
  VALIDATION_ID VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @PARENT

SELECT 'PASSIVE','V098' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','E009' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','V201' UNION ALL
SELECT 'PASSIVE','V034'
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
 PRODUCT_LINE        COMPONENT    MODEL    YEARS    VALIDATION_ID  INVALID_VALIDATION_ID
 PASSIVE              RESISTOR    CARBON    2005    V114           V114
 PASSIVE              RESISTOR    CARBON    2005    V201,V098,V114 V114
'PASSIVE','RESISTOR','CARBON','2005','null,V114',V114
```

Thanks ....

Comment: Would be easy if you had a normalized data model.

Comment: @dnoeth: Not Authorised to change DB Structure.... :(

Comment: the column sequence in your `@PARENT` table does not conincide with the `INSERT` statement

Comment: @Squirrel: Corrected.......Thanks...:)

Comment: oh my .. . literally `null`

Comment: The current query will still be able to handle `NULL` or `'null'`. You try and see if it suites your requirement

Comment: @Squirrel: sorry. but current query is giving even this 2 row which it should not.( PASSIVE RESISTOR CARBON 2005 NULL NULL)
(PASSIVE RESISTOR CARBON 2005 null,V098,E009  null)

Comment: @Squirrel: if we run present query we will get 4 records in output, but output should only 2 not null records.

Comment: oh . . you mean to ignore the `null` ?

Comment: @Squirrel: yes. if there is only NULL or NULL with valid validation_id. but null with invalid validation_id, then that record should appear in the output.

Comment: @Squirrel: wow.... Thanks a lot.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will definately required a CSV splitter. There are many, just search for it. Here I am using Jeff's [DelimitedSplit8K()](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
SELECT  c.*, INVALID_VALIDATION_ID = v.Item
FROM    @CHILD c
        CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(c.VALIDATION_ID, ',') v
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
(
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @PARENT p
        WHERE   p.PRODUCT_LINE  = c.PRODUCT_LINE
        and p.VALIDATION_ID = LTRIM(v.Item)
)
```

if there are more than one invalid ID, it will appear as multiple line. If you want the multiple invalid ID to appear as CSV, you will need additional query to concatenate it. Let me know if you required that

EDIT : Updated query to show invalid ID in CSV

```
; WITH
CTE AS
(
    SELECT  c.*, INVALID_VALIDATION_ID = v.Item, 
        RN = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PRODUCT_LINE, COMPONENT, MODEL, YEARS, VALIDATION_ID)
    FROM    @CHILD c
            CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(c.VALIDATION_ID, ',') v
    WHERE   c.VALIDATION_ID IS NOT NULL -- edit [2]
    AND     NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    @PARENT p
            WHERE   p.PRODUCT_LINE  = c.PRODUCT_LINE
            and p.VALIDATION_ID = LTRIM(v.Item)
        )
)
SELECT  DISTINCT 
    PRODUCT_LINE, COMPONENT, MODEL, YEARS, VALIDATION_ID,
    INVALID_VALIDATION_ID   = STUFF(csv, 1, 1, '')
FROM    CTE c
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT  ',' + x.INVALID_VALIDATION_ID
        FROM    CTE x
        WHERE   x.RN    = c.RN
        ORDER BY INVALID_VALIDATION_ID
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) i (csv)
```

Comment: How can we handle NULL , if NULL Is not present with parent but present with child, then it is fine, and need not appear in output.
kindly suggest.

Comment: what do you mean ? for example ?

Comment: for eg: for product line resistor there is NULL present in child table and not present in parent table
then it is appearing in result , but i don't want NULL to be treat like invalid validation_id. and it should not
appear in output.

Comment: a string contain 2 valid validation_id, and 1 NULL, Then it should not be in output due to NULL

Comment: i have added two more lines in child table with NULL those two lines should not appear in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Try This...

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT  c.*, INVALID_VALIDATION_ID = x.Value
    FROM    @CHILD c
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(c.VALIDATION_ID, ',') x
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    @PARENT p
        WHERE   p.PRODUCT_LINE  = c.PRODUCT_LINE
       and p.VALIDATION_ID = x.Value
    )  
) AS Q
WHERE INVALID_VALIDATION_ID IS NOT NULL AND  INVALID_VALIDATION_ID != 'null'
```

Here dbo.split function is ..

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(@List varchar(8000),@SplitOn varchar(5))

RETURNS @RtnValue table
(Id int identity(1,1),Value nvarchar(100))

AS
BEGIN
    Set @List = Replace(@List,'''','')
    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)

    Begin
            Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
            Select
            Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))

            Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
    Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

    Return
END
```

try this......